# Remove touchpointer in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I was trying to make a webapp with html elements that will move form *div* to antoher *div* when clicked but also I want to be able fire event when users hold that element for more than a second. So I have this code

```
$(document).on("click",'.card', function() {
    var card=$(this).parent();
    if(card.parent().attr('id')==="options"){
          card.appendTo("#choice");
    }
    else{
        card.appendTo("#options");
    }
});
var timeoutId = 0;
$('.card').on('pointerdown', function() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(showModal, 1000);
}).on('pointerup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);    
});
```

And it is doing almost fine. The problem occures when the element is clicked. It is appended to different div as it should but the mobile pointer is still on it so when I try to fire 'hold' event on another element it is not working for the first time since 'pointerup' event from previous element is firing right after 'pointerdown' event (So you need to try to hold next element twice).

I've dealt with it by adding a simple boolean flag in click event function so it is blocking next first call of 'pointerup' event but this is a very ugly solution.
Do you have any ideas how can i improve this? Maybe there is a way to call 'pointerup' event manually after click?

Answer (score 0):

Removing 'mouseleave' event and adding 'pointerleave' instead fixed the problem.
Not really sure how 'mouseleave' event was fired on mobile device though.